# Does anyone know how to change the web page title while the page is loading without Vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, titlebar

Right now, I'm moving from one page to another without Vue-router, instead I'm using window.location.href to set the direction of the page. Whenever the page moves and loads, the title that is rendered is the URL, and after it loads, whatever I set in the document.title in beforeCreate lifecycle is rendered.

I'm not sure if this is a default browser behavior, or it can be changed. Can someone enlighten me? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

i try many web page,it's always first show url then 0.1s less show title;

t tnink you can use `document.title = xxxxx` in your target page

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. Let me explain why this happens when you use `window.location.href` to change url.

When you are not using `vue-router` to change urls and use `window.location.href`, the browser makes an http request for the page (index.html) to your server. So, while the http request is fetching the browser does not have any idea about the html of the page and thus does not know the title of the page. So it simply shows the only known thing about the page, that is the URL. When the http request resolves and the javascript and vue initializes, the `beforeCreate` hook runs and the page title is set to your preference.

When you use `vue-router` there is no http call to server, all is done using javascript and vue. The title is changed using javascript and vue. No page reload happens.

Hope this helps